# taxonomy terms that get URL aliases and then end up being ugly google sitelinks

Tags: 6, navigation, taxonomy-terms

Including tags of course. I used some tags like  that I thought would be running in the background to use them as view filters, but then end up being google sitelinks such as 'subject-teaser-list'. How ugly and unprofessional that looks!

I rather have no sitelinks at all instead of these ugly looking sitelinks. 
You have this result when search google for 'breinwijzer'

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

you can manage which links are used for sitelinks in [Google's webmaster tools](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/10/webmasters-can-now-provide-feedback-on.html).

To change the description that is used you can use [nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) (or [metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) for D7).

[Here](http://www.pagetender.com/blog/bid/67581/Google-Sitelinks-Show-Off-Your-SEO-Efforts) is some more info about the recent change in Google's sitelinks feature.

Comment: Great info. Going to work with that. Knew already about the webmaster tools but degrading links you don't want for 90 days doesn't seem efficient. nodewords might be what I'm looking for though.